# Unable to read data bytes from input stream in java tcp socket

Tags: java, tcp, inputstream

In my Server code, I send different request to client and get back the response but only first read request is accessed, during accessing second read statement,it is unable to read Data bytes,my code is as followed.

```
private static boolean Rt_Request(int id,Object client)throws Exception  
{ 

int size=5; 

byte[] buf=new byte[size];

char[] cbuf=new char[32]; 

int byteRead; Socket s=(Socket)client;


BufferedReader in1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

PrintStream out=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

try {
    buf[0]=0x02;            
    buf[1]=0x09;            
    buf[2]=0x01;            
    buf[3]=0x00;            
    buf[4]=0x03;
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    out.write(buf, 0, 5);      
} catch(Exception e) {        
     System.out.println("Error Occured...."+e);                             
}

byteRead=0;

while(byteRead!=1) {
        try {

            byteRead=in1.read(cbuf, 0, 1);// Have problem on this line,here I am unable to read data bytes.
            for(int i=0;i<byteRead;i++)
            {
            System.out.println(cbuf[i]);
            }
            if(byteRead==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Breaking.....");
                return false;
            }         
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured...."+e);
            return false;
        }

    }       
        return true;   
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("System is not Connected..."+e);
        return false;
    }
```

almost tried every thing socket is not closed, read.available();,read.fully(); etc..unable to get the solution.I have written this function in the run method of TimerTask class.
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're telling it to read only one byte. How's cbuf declared?

Comment: actually I want to read 32 bytes, for testing purpose I replaced 32 by 1,char[] cbuf=new char[32];..it is how I am declaring cbuf

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the first half of the code. Am I missing something?

Comment: private static boolean Rt_Request(int id,Object client)throws Exception
    {
        int size=5;
        byte[] buf=new byte[size];
        char[] cbuf=new char[32];
        int byteRead;
        Socket s=(Socket)client;
this is what I skipped earlier, d concept is I am sending 5 bytes real time request and I want to read 32 bytes response, First I send 5 Bytes mac-id request and I can read successfully 5 bytes response as well this is 2nd time I am facing problem while I am reading the 32 bytes.It shows that my input stream have no value in it but d same client is working fine wit .NET model

Comment: @Reshma Please don't do that. You can see for yourself that code in comments is entirely illegible. Edit it into your post.

Comment: @EJP..I am sorry but I didn't got what you want to say,is it that I have coded it wrong or something else,please explain it.

Comment: @Reshma Putting code into comments is what I am talking about.

Comment: @EJP..I have written the Real Time function in run method of TimerTask class,is it creating any problem..??? ,because when I am calling this real time function from main method then it is executing well,but my program needs a timer function since I have to check the database frequently and update it as soon as I get data from client

Answer (score 0):

the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)  says BufferedReader#read(char[], int, int) Returns:
The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

since you do

```
byteRead=in1.read(cbuf, 0, 1);
```

in

`while(byteRead!=1)`

change it to

```
while(byteRead != -1)
```

Comment: Sorry,but it is not helping, I replaced it but as soon as I step on this statement  byteRead=in1.read(cbuf, 0, 32);  then it is not stepping further and doesn't give any result.

Comment: try putting it like this `while((byteRead=in1.read(cbuf, 0, 1)) != -1)` I don't know whether this will work but I have always used it like this

Comment: Nopes...as soon as I placed that statement in while loop then loop statement hanged..no further work is done...it is the read method which is creating the problem I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

```
byteRead=in1.read(cbuf, 0, 1);
```

This line only reads in one value and as you don't call it again before you enter the for loop, you should be getting 1 println of the value that was read in displayed in stdout.

Comment: That is storing my data bytes in cbuf which is a buffer of 32 bytes which then I am printing in for loop, my main problem is as soon as I step to this statement byteRead=in1.read(cbuf, 0, 32); no further operation is performed ,actually it hangs over there ,only first request I can read properly so it doesn't matter if it's of 32 bytes or 5 bytes

Comment: private static boolean Rt_Request(int id,Object client)throws Exception
    {
        int size=5;
        byte[] buf=new byte[size];
        char[] cbuf=new char[32];
        byte [] my_data=new byte[1];
        int byteRead;
        Socket s=(Socket)client;
this is what I haven't paste earlier

Answer (score 0):

The [read method of the underlying `InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) will block (i.e. hang/wait) if no data is available.

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

I strongly suspect this is the case.
You can check this by calling `in1.ready()` on the reader.

Flush the output buffer

`out.flush();`

after writing the bytes, or they may get buffered locally.

Comment: I did used that too but then in1.ready hangs, actually my model is in java and one more mode is in .NET, R both server communicates with client GPRS gateway but .NET server receives all response and I am unable to receive more than one response, first I got the response for 5 bytes of MAC-ID request,then I interchanged that function with 32 bytes   and I got 32 bytes of real time request but then unable to get 5 bytes of MAC-ID request

Comment: in1.ready() should return true or false, are you certain it hangs?

Comment: @flup...yes,it hangs,when this statement is access then it doesn't step in further.

Comment: It is executed in the runtime, perhaps your debugger doesn't have the sources to step into. Can you print or inspect its return value? Also, flush the output stream when you want it to send.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` blocks until at least one byte is available. Maybe you haven't sent it, or flushed it properly, or maybe you are creating multiple `BufferedReaders` on the same socket.

NB `bytesRead` can never be zero after a successful `read(cbuf, 0, 1).`

Comment: @EJP...Yes, I have created multiple BufferedReaders but they are through different threads, Do it affect...???

Comment: The data from a stream can only be buffered in one buffer of course. Don't put multiple readers on the same stream.